# Appended Elements Using .on Method Unable To Be Removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery is deciding to be dumb or I'm simply missing something, but removing appended elements does not work for me using the following code:

```
$('#add-show').click(function() {
    if ( $('#fav-search').val() == '' ) {
        // do nothing
    }
    else {
        $('.fav-results').append('<code><a href="#"><span class="icon-remove"></span></a>' + $('#fav-search').val() + '</code>');
    }
});

$('.fav-results code').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

And the HTML for anyone who is interested:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input class="span2" id="fav-search" type="text">
    <button class="btn" type="button" id="add-show"><span class="icon-plus"></span></button>
</div>
<div class="pull-right fav-results">
    <?php foreach($shows as $show): ?>
        <code><a href="#"><span class="icon-remove"></span></a><?php echo $show['showname'] ?></code>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Existing titles pulled from my database table are able to be removed but no appended elements can be.

I originally was using a .click handler but I read that it only works for elements existing in the DOM at the time of page load. After reading previous questions of the same nature I changed to using .on but it's still acting the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `click` event to apply to dynamically created elements, you should delegate it to the ancestor `<div>` instead of the `<code>` elements:

```
$(".fav-results").on("click", "code a", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `remove()` instead of `detach()` which is removing the event handlers on all of the `code` elements before they are executed.